# Where does git store the config file for all user in OS X?

Tags: git

According to Git Pro it should be here:

**/etc/gitconfig** - all users and their repos. ( not on OSX[])

However I do not see this file.

Is it somewhere else or do I need to create it?

Comment: Are you running an OS X server for which you need a system-wide `gitconfig` file? Your personal `.gitconfig` file is located in the root of your home directory `~/.gitconfig`

Comment: I know where  that file is but there is suppose to be a file for **all** users in the location I listed according to Git Pro.

Comment: is it in `/usr/local/etc/gitconfig`? That's where it is for me because I installed via homebrew, thus my `$(prefix)` is `/usr/local`

Comment: Nope it's not there.

Comment: Are you using git installed via command line tools or homebrew? What's the output of `git --version`?

Comment: If command line tools, try here: `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/etc/gitconfig`

Comment: Not there, I don't remember honestly, I think it came when I installed node.js but I'm not sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96363/discussion-between-hbhb-and-cade-galt).

Answer (score 4):

read `git config --help` on your system

as you can see, this file can be managed with the `git config` command

however on my system

```
$ git config --system -l
fatal: unable to read config file '/etc/gitconfig': No such file or directory
```

This is because I have never set one up!  This is normal

I do use `git config --global` which is the per user file but not the above
which is per server

Comment: On my Mac (using `/usr/bin/git`), the path is `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/etc/gitconfig` (which also doesn't exist by default).

Comment: this is a broken option ... it tries to access this file and it is not there.  I don't even have that directory.  But there should be a way for any git user to setup system wide configurations, even on OS X.

Comment: @cade gait there is, just run ``git config --system -e`` as root

Answer (score 2):

I have Mac os Sierra and I have installed git from [here](https://git-scm.com/downloads) . I think system level file location might change depending on how you have installed git in your mac like if you installing it with brew (`$ brew install git`).

For local git config files , see for a hidden folder in your git project by name of `.git`. Inside you will have `config` file.

For global level git config file , `$HOME/.gitconfig` is the file.

For system level file , I have the file in `/usr/local/git/etc/gitconfig`.

In case , this does not matches yours and assuming config files exist , you can run the command

```
git config --system -–edit
git config --global --edit
git config --local --edit
```

Then your editor will open up and from there you can see what location these files reside. For me , I have set up Sublime Editor and then I just do `File -> Open` and I can see the location of this file.

Answer (score -1):

The `.gitconfig` file may not exist when you first install git. In that case, you'll need to create it. On mac

```
$ vim ~/.gitconfig
```

and then

```
$ source ~/.gitconfig
```

and it should then be globally available.

Comment: OP is asking about global config for **all** users; the home dir config for specific users.

Comment: Also, this question was asked and answered over 7 years ago. Unless you have a substantially *better* answer, don't answer it.

Comment: That IS where the config file goes for all users. Also, things can change over 7 years. Nothing wrong with keeping an answer updated.